# Writing on-request filtering for related objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

Suppose that we have following models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)

class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="items")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Categories and their items are listed like so

```
def view(request):
   categories = Category.objects.all()
   pass

{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category.name }}
    {% for item in category.items.all %}
        {{ item.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In this structure, I want to write on-request filtering for listed 'items'.

```
def view(request):
    ...
    queryset = ???
    state = request.GET.get('state')
    if state:
        queryset = queryset.filter(state__name=state)
```

The problem is defining 'queryset'. Because, Items are listed as related objects of category.

Can it be done properly? or Do I need to change design?

You can take a look at my design to be more clear.

[Low fidelity design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Yqo6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `related_name` in the Item object for category field should be named "items". Then category.items.all will give you the list of items in that category. Look at the example in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name).

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        Article,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="tags",
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

To filter items depending on category you can pass the PKs of the category in the request and filter according to those specific categories.

```
views.py
def your_view(request):
    ...
    list_of_your_category_ids = [1,4] #get them as a list from frontend
    list_of_your_state_names = [1,2] 
    queryset =  Item.objects.filter(
                category__in=list_of_your_category_ids,
                state__code__in=list_of_your_category_names
            )
```

This will give you the queryset you wanted. Now all you need is to regroup this queryset with their categories.

Django provides a [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag that does exactly this.

```
{% regroup queryset by category as categories_list %}
<ul>
    {% for category in categories_list %}
    <li>
        {{category.grouper}}
        <ul>            
            {% for item in category.list %}
            <li>
                {{item}}: state - {{item.state.code}}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %} 
</ul>
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbTpz.png
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I made a mistake while writing the sample code.
But, In the code, we already suppose that category.items.all, works.
The problem is writing on-request filtering for that items.
Is it possible for you to reconsider your reply?

Comment: To make sure I understand the problem. What you want to do is, given a category let's say category with PK = 1, you want to get all the items in this given category. Is that correct?

Comment: Let's say we're listing categories and their items. There is no problem for this, as I mentioned in the code. But I want to write dynamic filter for the listed items.Actually, if you take a look at my question one more time, it'll be much more clear.

Comment: Edited my answer. Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: I really appreciate your effort to help me. There is a structure where more than one category will be located on the same section. so, I don't think that solution is suitable for me. I added my low fidelity design in my question.  Could you check this?

Comment: Alright Morty, I edited another time the answer. I hope this one helps.